# "Standard Deviation If" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column which contains numbers and want to compute their standard deviation only  for positive numbers.

For example, if the numbers are 3, 2, -1, -6, 7, -4, 0, 10, -15, then the result should be 3.20, as the computation should only consider 3, 2, 7, and 10.

In normal Excel, I can do this like:

`STDEV.P(IF(RANGE > 0, RANGE))` and press `Control + Shift + Enter`.

How would I do this in VBA?

Comment: How are you defining you range? `NamedRange`, a set range, everything in Column `a` etc - I'll get you an example ready

Comment: @Badja In Excel, `range` looks like B2:B100

Comment: Is that a constant, or can more be added to the bottom?

Comment: @Badja For this problem it is OK to assume that it is constant

Comment: For VBA, just use `.FormulaArray` and use your regular formula, `Cells(1, 1).FormulaArray = "=STDEV(IF(B2:B100>0,B2:B100))"`

Comment: @Cyril I would like to perform the  computation within VBA and get the result (double type value) within VBA and assign it into a variable.

Comment: @JunJang you can do that and set `.value=.value` and be done, or you can do the longer winded calculation in VBA where you perform the averge then subtract from each if >0, etc.  I'd choose the simple use of your formula + the value=value into the same cell

Comment: You can use `Evaluate` directly within VBA to evaluate formulas, including array formulas.  Be sure to use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` form to ensure your formula is evaluated in the correct context.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

This allows you to set the range outside of the formula, in case you want to use it elsewhere

```
Sub StandDev()

Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("StandDev") 'Worksheet name
    Set rng = ws.Range("B2", "B100") 'Your range

    With Cells(1, 1) 'Cell "A1"
    .FormulaArray = "=STDEV.P(IF(" & rng.Address & "> 0," & rng.Address & "))"
    .Value = .Value 'Your formula
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Or `ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = ws.Evaluate("=STDEV.P(IF(" & rng.Address & "> 0," & rng.Address & "))")`   `Evaluate` is smart enough to figure out it's to be run as an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

Example of the longer stdev function with positive number criteria (untested, general walkthrough)

```
for i = startrow to endrow
    if cells(i,1).value > 0 then
        redim preserve arr(ubound(arr)+1)
        arr(ubound(arr)) = cells(i,1).value
        x = x + cells(i,1).value
        n = n + 1
    end if
next i
```

Now youv'e collected all values you need...

- Average = x/n
- Array *arr* has all viable values so you can use your (value - average)^2 [your summation]

Perform general calculation with your double variable.

---

If you can get away with it, same as my comment, use your existing formula with `.FormulaArray`, then `value=value`, such that:

```
Cells(1, 1).FormulaArray = "=STDEV(IF(B2:B100>0,B2:B100))"
Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value
```